# Is there a connection between the serpent in Eden and the brass serpent in the wilderness?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, chukas, gan-eden

Often unrelated stories are related to each other, (sometimes even despite non similar words). In this present case, one particular animal has a (some kind of) central role to its development. In the first cenario, the serpent of Eden is presented as having cunningness (more than other animal) and he speaks, and argues and so on. Then after, the serpent presents itself to Chava as a chance to gain some type a divine status. But the story goes bad, and the end is well known. The same is true with the brass serpent in the midbar. It was good in the first moment, then goes bad.

Is there any commentary that makes a connection and/or distinction between the serpent in Eden and the the brass serpent in the wilderness? If so, what they say and what connection and/or distinction they draw about it?

Related: [Why did Moses raise the brass serpent in the wilderness?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4668/why-did-moses-raise-the-brass-serpent-in-the-wilderness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Rashi, Numbers 21:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9949/showrashi/true#v6) (citing earlier Midrashim):

> Let the snake, which was smitten for speaking evil [to Eve], come and punish those who spread slander [about the manna]. Let the snake, for which all types of food taste the same, come and punish those ingrates, for whom one thing [the manna] changes into various tastes.

So the connection is between the serpent and the snakes that were sent to punish the Jewish people, for which the brass snake (or rather, the looking upward to G-d that it engendered - see [Rashi ibid. verse 8](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9949/showrashi/true#v8)) was the antidote.