# Serpants (snakes) or Seraphim (heavenly beings of some sort)?

Tags: commentaries, chukas

I read [different](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1814/why-make-a-copper-snake?rq=1) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4668/why-did-moses-raise-the-brass-serpent-in-the-wilderness) on this matter from 'mi yodeya' but I couldn't find my answer:

In Numbers 21:6 HaShem brings  הנְּחָשִׁים הַשְּׂרָפִים upon the people...
In Numbers 21:8 HaShem commands Moshe to make a שָׂרָף (saraph) and וְשִׂים אֹתוֹ עַל־נֵס(to put it on a flag/pennant/standard).
In Numbers 21:9 Moshe makes a נְחַשׁ נְחֹשֶׁת (brass serpent) and וַיְשִׂמֵהוּ עַל־הַנֵּס (put it on a flag/pennant/standard) which according to this verse helped to solve the matter.

שרף seems to have to do with 'burning', but the same word is also used to describe some heavenly beings as in Yeshayahu 6:2

So what attacked the people and what did Moshe had to make: a seraph (like he did) or a saraph (like HaShem said him, but might indeed refer to a serpent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chukas 21:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9949#v=6&showrashi=true) is translated as

> 6. The Lord sent against the people the venomous snakes, and they bit the
>      people, and many people of Israel died.

Rashi explains that these are

> the venomous snakes: Heb. הַנְּחָשִׁים הַשְּׂרָפִים, lit. the burning
>   snakes, [so named] because they ‘burn’ a person with the venom of
>   their fangs. — [Midrash Tanchuma Chukkath 19, Num. Rabbah 19:22]

Similarly, Moshe Rabbeinu made an image of the actual serpent that was attacking.

[Chukas 21:8 - 9](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9949#v=8&showrashi=true)

> 8 The Lord said to Moses, "Make yourself a serpent and put it on a
>   pole, and let whoever is bitten look at it and live.
>
> 9 Moses made a copper snake and put it on a pole, and whenever a snake
>   bit a man, he would gaze upon the copper snake and live.

Rav Hirsch explains that the people had become complacent as a result of Hashem protecting them from the **normal** dangers of the wilderness such as the poisonous snakes that were found there. As a result, they were attacked by the normal type of snakes that were to be found. As Rav Hirsch translates 21:6

> Then Hashem let the poisonous serpents loose against the people, and
>   they bit the people and many people of Israel died.

Rav Hirsch explains that

> שלח in the Kal means to send to put something in motion towards a
>   goal. But שַלֵחַ in Piel predominantly has the meaning of letting
>   something go, to leave it to its natural way, not to hold it back.

Thus, we see in Noach when he sent out the raven and the dove and in other places.

> Here too, not Hashem **sent** serpents, but let them go, did not keep
>   them back. Hence not נחשים שרפים but הנחשים השרפים, they had always
>   been there in the wilderness, but hitherto they had been kept back by
>   Hashem's careful protecting Power.

This means that the term *burning* is a reference to the physical nature of the serpents and does not refer to the *Seraphim* that you reference from Yeshaya. The reason for the usage of the term there is because on a spiritual level the navi *saw* beings of *fire*. The two places refer to completely different concepts.